# Execute script inside another exits outer script

Tags: bash, command-line

I try to launch another app inside a bash script, but the app seems to exit my script so that the line `exec $HOME/bin/sync-iosbeta;` does not get executed. I have tried to put it outside the if as well.

```
if $HOME/bin/BetaBuilder.app/Contents/MacOS/BetaBuilder --args -i "${zip}" -o "${odir}" -u "${ourl}" -r "$PROJECT_FOLDER/README.txt" ; then
    echo "Wil sync"
    exec $HOME/bin/sync-iosbeta;
fi

echo "This text does not get printed either..";
```

I have also tried to use `open` to kick off the app, but then I have issues with passing the arguments, even with `--args` set.

I am running on Mac OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **exec** manual:

> If command is specified, it replaces the shell. No new process is created.

Just remove exec and the ";":

```
if $HOME/bin/BetaBuilder.app/Contents/MacOS/BetaBuilder --args -i "${zip}" -o "${odir}" -u "${ourl}" -r "$PROJECT_FOLDER/README.txt" ; then
    echo "Wil sync"
    $HOME/bin/sync-iosbeta
fi

echo "This text does not get printed either..";
```

If **sync-iosbeta** is not being executed, then may be it hasn't the right permissions. Try:

```
if $HOME/bin/BetaBuilder.app/Contents/MacOS/BetaBuilder --args -i "${zip}" -o "${odir}" -u "${ourl}" -r "$PROJECT_FOLDER/README.txt" ; then
    echo "Wil sync"
    /bin/sh $HOME/bin/sync-iosbeta
fi

echo "This text does not get printed either..";
```

Comment: I see, I have removed the exec. but then it only prints out: File not found. `/package-app: line 94: /BetaBuilder.app/Contents/MacOS/BetaBuilder -i DeploymentTest-7910-7910.zip -o DeploymentTest-DeploymentTest-7910-7910 -u DeploymentTest-DeploymentTest-7910-7910: No such file or directory
BetaBuilder encountered an error. Check system logs.`

It works if I run the exact same command in terminal. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1):

That's the whole point of exec. `man bash`: If command is specified, it replaces the shell.

just remove `exec`.